# Is this function monotonically increasing as $x_2$ increases?

Tags: integration, functions, monotone-functions, centroid

Suppose I have a differentiable and continuous function $f(x)>0$, the monotonicity of $f(x)$ is unknown.

Assume that $x_1< x_2< x_3 \in \mathcal{S}$, $\mathcal{S}$ is the domain of $f(x)$.

let $g(x)$ be
\begin{equation}
g(x_2)=2x_2-\frac{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}xf(x)dx}{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)dx}-\frac{\int_{x_2}^{x_3}xf(x)dx}{\int_{x_2}^{x_3}f(x)dx}
\end{equation}

Actually, $g(x_2)$ is the $2x_2$ minus the sum of centroids in $(x_1,x_2)$ and in $(x_2,x_3)$.

My question is :

Is $g(x_2)$ is **monotonically increasing** as $x_2$ increases?

Some **MatLab simulation results** show that $g(x_2)$ seems to be a monotonically increasing of $x_2$.
But, can we theoretically show this?

I have tried to see if the derivation of $g(x_2)$ is always large than $0$, but the result is not explicit.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks for the answer from **@Greg Martin**.

Actually, in my problem, $f(x)$ is an asymmetrical probability density function with $x\geq 0$.

Now, I still have a question: Does $g(x)=0$ have and only have **one** root?

Thanks for any helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. One idea for constructing a counterexample: suppose that $f(x)$ is an even function that is large at the endpoints of an interval $[-a,a]$ but small in the middle. Then when $x$ is not close to $a$, the centroid of the region under the graph of $y=f(x)$ on $[-a,x]$ will be very close to $-a$; but when $x$ approaches $a$, the centroid abruptly approaches $0$, at as high as a rate as we might like to arrange.

For a specific counterexample, take $f(x)=x^4$ and $(x_1,x_3) = (-1,2)$. In this case, $g(x)$ is decreasing from about $x=0.8$ to about $x=1.35$. (Here $f(x)$ is not strictly positive, but adding a tiny constant to $f(x)$ doesn't change $g(x)$ that much.)

Comment: Thanks for @Greg Martin. 
Your answer is clear and vivid!
^_^